# device.makeCommandQueue() gives Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: metal

This line

```
commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()
```

gives runtime error

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

```
import UIKit
import MetalKit

enum Colors{
    static let ClearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.0,
                                          green: 0.21,
                                          blue: 0.4,
                                          alpha: 1.0)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var metalView: MTKView{
        return view as! MTKView
    }

    var device: MTLDevice!
    var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        metalView.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        device = metalView.device

        metalView.clearColor = Colors.ClearColor

        commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()
        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()

        let commandEncoder =
          commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: metalView.currentRenderPassDescriptor!)

        commandEncoder?.endEncoding()
        commandBuffer?.present(metalView.currentDrawable!)
        commandBuffer?.commit()
    }

}
```

Comment: This is probably happening because your `MTLDevice` actually is nil. Can you tell us where you're running the app (which Mac or iOS device)? It's possible that Metal isn't supported on the device you're deploying to.

Comment: I am running the app on Mac.

Comment: Isn't the app running in simulator？how to？

Comment: iOS simulator can't emulate Metal calls, so `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` returns `nil`, since there are no Metal devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the comments you've left, you are trying to run iOS application that uses Metal  on macOS using iOS simulator.

Unfortunately, even though Metal is supported on macOS, running Metal under iOS simulator this is *not* supported.

And since Metal is not supported, `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` returns `nil`, which then causes the error you've mentioned.

If you want your code to run on both macOS and iOS, you would need to write your app so that it's cross-platform. If it's an app that just renders stuff on screen, without tons of UI, like a game, it should be pretty straightforward, since Xcode provides a template for a cross-platform project that uses Metal.

Comment: Good news: In Xcode 11 the iOS 13 Simulator supports Metal when running on macOS 10.15.